# Can I use std::copy to copy arrays allocated on heap?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt6, C++ 11, I declare two 2d arrays of dynamic sizes:

```
int **A; int **B;
A = new int*[rowCount]();
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    A[i] = new int[colCount]();   //Same for B
}
// Then feed A with some incoming values
```

and I want to copy all A's values to B, I know that using std::copy is faster and cleaner than using for -loop, so I tried:

```
 std::copy(&A[0][0], &A[0][0]+rowCount*colCount,&B[0][0]);
```

However I got error message:

```
code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)
```

Looks like I am trying to access memories not allocated? But I have already allocated two arrays on the heap

Why I don't use 2d vector or list is that I need to process large amount of data and accessing array by index is O(1), if you think this is caused by my compiler I can provide make file and project file snippets. Thank you very much

**Edit:** @Miles Budnek pointed out that std::vector and raw C++ array have similar indexing performances (both O(1)). I am handing large amount of data, the way I store and read data is basically indexing.

I have tested std::vector and C++ array indexing performances under MSVC 2019 64-bit, C++ 11 using Qt creator and I found they are similar(std::vector even a little bit faster), if under most environments(like various compilers) std::vector and raw C++ array are both O(1), I would say std::vector is safer and more convenient than C++ raw arrays.

But it looks like QVector indexing speed is much lower?

Comment: A `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is exactly the same as a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of `int`s in memory layout and access complexity.  You gain nothing by managing the memory yourself.

Comment: The function `std::copy` requires: 1) Source is a valid location, has data, and is readable.  2) The destination is a valid location and can be writeable.  3) Destination can be reached by incrementing the source location.  So if your heap meets these requirements, then `std::copy` should work.  Also, the locations between source and destination must be readable and valid locations.

Comment: @MilesBudnek But accessing vector by index is not O(1), I have some performance issues that's why I use array instead of vector or list

Comment: `std::vector` has constant-time indexing, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: You should declare your 2d matrix as a contiguous 1d array.  This will allow you to use one pass of `std::copy`.  Otherwise, you need to use `std::copy` *on each row*, because there is no guarantee that the memory is contiguous for each call to `operator new`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I have to say you pointed out a new path for me... Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `std::copy` to copy your array as a single chunk because you do not have a single array.  What you have is a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to the first element of arrays of `int`s.  That is, assuming `rowCount` and `colCount` are both 3, you have this:

```
A
┌───┐
│   │
│ │ │
│ │ │
└─┼─┘
  │
  ▼
┌───┐
│   │        ┌───┬───┬───┐
│ ──┼───────►│ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │
│   │        └───┴───┴───┘
├───┤
│   │        ┌───┬───┬───┐
│ ──┼───────►│ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │
│   │        └───┴───┴───┘
├───┤
│   │        ┌───┬───┬───┐
│ ──┼───────►│ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │
│   │        └───┴───┴───┘
└───┘
```

As you can see, there is no contiguous chunk of elements for `std::copy` to copy.

If you want to be able to efficiently copy (and access) elements of your array, you should allocate a single array that is `rowCount*colCount` long.  If you want nice syntax you could wrap it up in a class and overload the `()` or `[]` operator to make the access nicer.  For example:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int rowSize_;
    std::vector<int> storage_;
public:
    Matrix(int rowCount, int colCount)
         : rowSize_{colCount},
           storage_(rowCount * colCount)
    {}

    int& operator()(int row, int col)
    {
        return storage_[row * rowSize_ + col];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Matrix mat{3, 3};
    mat(1, 2) = 42;

    // copy with simple copy construction
    Matrix mat2 = mat;

    // or copy-assignment
    mat2 = mat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very detailed and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't guarantee that each call to `new[]` will generate consecutive locations for the rows.

Your 2d array is actually a **1d array of pointers to random memory locations**.  There is no guarantee that the beginning of one row follows the end of the previous row.

So, to copy your 2d array, you'll have to loop through the rows, copying each row separately:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row)
{
    std::copy(&A[row], &B[row], colCount);
}
```

If you allocate the 2d array at contiguous locations, you could then use one call to `std::copy`:

```
int A[MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLUMNS];
int B[MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLUMNS];
std::copy(&A[0], &B[0], MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLUMNS);
```